# How to make objects not pass through each other?

Tags: animation, objects, physics, collision

I have a field with plants, and some plant's leaves are cross over with each other. How do I add collision/or is there any other way to solve this problem?

I need that effect, cause I'm creating a field with 100+ randomly placed and generated plants on scene via scripting, and I need it to look close to real field.
My plant is armatured and animated(wind-like effect)

Here's [rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiQOR.jpg).
That's what I'm talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by applying Soft Body (with a few settings, so my objects won't jump around) and Collision effects

[image]